# Type a word from the keyboard and store each letter into a series of multiple input text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I would like to present to the user several `input` text box that allows them to type a string of letters or characters that stores one letter into each box in a 'spill-over' manner. Each box is an input text type that has a limit of 1 character.

[image]

For example, the image above shows 3 input boxes (don't count the first box which shows the first letter of a word). If I type continuously a s t, 'a' should go into box2, 's' into box3 and 't' into box4. Is this possible?

At the moment, I can only manage to type one letter per box and then either have to hit the tab key or use the mouse to move the focus to the next input box on the right.

What magical CSS/HTML/Javascript would I be needing for me to complete this Quest, Sire?

Reference/Related:
http://moodurian.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-i-managed-to-allow-input-of-only-1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a jquery solution, than you can use `.keyup()` event, and an `if` condition, which will check the length of the `input` filed, if it exceeds `1`, it will `focus` the very next field.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GUaZB/)

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val().length >= 1) {
      var input_flds = $(this).closest('form').find(':input');
      input_flds.eq(input_flds.index(this) + 1).focus();
    }
});
```

Make sure you also use `maxlength` attribute on your `input` fields, so that a user typing fast may not exceed the character limit.

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/GUaZB/1/)

Comment: Hi Mr. Alien. Thanks the jsfiddle code works! What should I do if I have several other forms input boxes all around my screen but I want to limit this effect (spill-over of each letter) to only one form set of three input boxes?

Comment: @user1029442 assign a class to your form element and do something like `$("form.class_name input")`

Comment: Hi Mr Alien. Yes!!! I used this JQuery code: 
$("span.ipadsize input").keyup(function() 
{ 
   ... 
} 
instead. Then in my source code, I used <span class="ipadsize">...</span> to enclose the input code. Works like a charm. Fabulous! Many thanks!!!

Comment: @user1029442 so does that work or not? if it does, than consider marking the answer as correct by clicking on the tick beside the answer :) http://jsfiddle.net/GUaZB/4/

Comment: @user1029442 you should mark post as an answer so that others get to know the correct answer

Comment: @Nitinvarpe I am the answerer :)

Comment: Hi Mr. Alien. How do I simulate a tab key. The reason I am asking is that as I type, the cursor automatically focuses on the next input box, but the contents of the box is not selected. I would like the contents of the box to be highlighted. So that it is easier for the user to overwrite the contents. If the contents of the next box is not selected, then the user may have to delete the contents and then type in the correct answer letter. More work for the user.

Comment: @user1029442 add `.select()` http://jsfiddle.net/GUaZB/5/, type in first, after you type in all the boxes, click on first box, type something and see it will focus the other field with the text selected

Comment: Hi Mr. Alien. Testing on a Windows7 PC, the focus moves to the next box and I can instantly type in my next letter input. HOWEVER, on an iPad2, after entering a letter into a box, the next box comes into focus but I have to tap the currently highted box to bring up the iPad virtual keyboard. Any comments?

Comment: @user1029442 Well, too many devices huh, so I don't for each one, so you can throw another question, may be ipad guys can help you :)

Comment: Yup too many devices these days. Can't keep up with them, but the main one was the desktop PC. And you helped me a lot today! Will follow your advice. Thanks Mr. Alien.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mr.Alien said, setting MaxLength property will safeguard the text box in having more than 1 character of text. Additionally, You should select the text in the text box while it is getting a focus. It will simplify the process if user starts from the first text box again.

```
$("input").keyup(function() {

      var input_flds = $(this).next("input");
      input_flds.select().focus();

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GUaZB/2/) It is a modified copy of @Mr.Alien demo

**Update:**

Implementing the above concept in a selected text box, [Concept: Set a class for the text boxes which you want to apply the need]

```
$("input").keyup(function() {

    var input_flds = $(this).nextAll(".test:first");
    input_flds.select().focus();

});

//where .test will be your class on the selected text boxes.
```

[DEMO - 1](http://jsfiddle.net/GUaZB/3/)

Comment: Hi RajaPrabhu - Many thanks for this! Yes it works beautifully. If you've ever in Malaysia, I'll treat you to a durian buffet. Hopefully you can eat the durian fruit ;-).

Comment: @user1029442 Thanks. see my new update for your original need. By the way, if you find my answer useful then accept it, to help the future referrers.

Comment: @RajaPrabhuOfficial Yes, I had kept that method for forms across, thank you for the refatoraction :)

Comment: How do I tick both answers as correct! Only One Green Tick allowed? :-(

Comment: @user1029442 No Problem, I have inherited a lot from the answer that you had accepted. Real credits should belongs to him. By the way, You can upvote my answer if it helped in solving your problems.