# Automatically generate a iPad tap event immediately after an input box is in focus

Tags: jquery, ipad, input

Yo, waddup?

I have a series of input boxes that allow me to type a string of letters or characters that stores one letter into each box in a 'spill-over' manner. Each box is an input text type that has a limit of 1 character.

It works fine on my web browser (in Windows). On the iPad however, after tapping the first letter inside the first input box, the second input box will highlight (focus), but the iPad's virtual keyboard will dropdown (disappear). I am then forced to tap the second input box to bring up the iPad's virtual keyboard.

Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/frankiekam/GUaZB/9/

**HTML**

```
<form>
   <input class="test" type="text" maxlength="1" />
   <input class="test" type="text" maxlength="1" />
   <input class="test" type="text" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="test" type="text" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="test" type="text" maxlength="1" />
    <input class="test" type="text" maxlength="1" />       
</form>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    var input_flds = $(this).nextAll(".test:first");
    input_flds.select().focus(); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=text] {
    width: 30px;
}
```

This is frustrating to use (on the iPad) as to enter the letters 'a', 's' and 't' as shown in the image example below, I have to do 6 six steps:

1. Tap to bring up iPad Virtual Keyboard
2. Key in 'a', focus moves on to second input box
3. Tap to bring up iPad Virtual Keyboard
4. Key in 's', focus moves on to third input box
5. Tap to bring up iPad Virtual Keyboard
6. Key in 't'
   Very tedius !!!

[image]

My Quest is this. I need to find a way for the Javascript/JQuery code to automatically register or create a iPad tap event right after the next input box is in focus.
The proper flow should be like this:

1. Tap to bring up iPad Virtual Keyboard (VK)
2. Key in 'a', focus moves on to second input box, tap event auto-generated, VK pops up.
3. Key in 's', focus moves on to third input box, tap event auto-generated, VK pops up.
4. Key in 't'.

What magical CSS/HTML/Javascript would I be needing for me to complete this Quest, Sire?

Reference/Related:
[Type a word from the keyboard and store each letter into a series of multiple input text boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557517/type-a-word-from-the-keyboard-and-store-each-letter-into-a-series-of-multiple-in)
and
http://moodurian.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-i-managed-to-allow-input-of-only-1.html

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function () {
    $(this).next().focus();
});
```

or

```
$('input').on('keyup', function () {
    $(this).next().click();
});
```

What this does is finds the next input after your key press and ensures that the next input field becomes focused by either clicking the field or directly focusing it.

Comment: this would be a better answer if you explained why it worked.

Comment: Sorry the code doesn't work. I tried it on my iPad Air.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y28jS/
and
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hnuEs