# Seperate boxes for each letter in an Input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I mean these [boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNBJY.png) ; I want to imitate a real form but im not sure how to go about this.. I know it's not possible with normal html and might require some javascript/jquery; An example of this form online is also appreciated!

[image]

Comment: CSS is your friend -- best start learning from the beginning.

Comment: I don't see how css can help me in this case; If you're talking about repeating image as the background, that's not what i meant :\

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557517/type-a-word-from-the-keyboard-and-store-each-letter-into-a-series-of-multiple-in

Comment: You mean that you need each letter to be in a separate input field or to look like it is?

Comment: It can just look 'boxified' but 'constraining' the textboxes might require kerning right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I dont think you need any js for this. You only need:

- An image of a box
- A monospaced font
- Some playing around with css values
- Some Phantasy

See this CSS applied to an input field:

```
#text{
    background-image: url("square.gif");    
    width: 195px;
    height: 18px;
    background-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 12px;
}
```

an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/w564j/

Comment: Sorry for that. Made an edit.

Comment: This works great, however I would want to limit the number of characters to 6. Doing so when the user types in the 6th character, the 7th box appears (however no entry is done). How can I keep a check that this does not happen?

Comment: Hi Zain, i don't really understand what exactly you want to achieve, could you make it more clear (maybe rephrase your question) or post a jsfiddle link ?

Comment: I posted a question yesterday, might be a good read for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746130/limit-the-number-of-characters-in-a-separate-input-field-for-each-character/38748367#38748367

Comment: Are you able to make this responsive? So the width of input is dynamic? Thanks

Comment: Yes, this could be cone with javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by with `keypress` event on every input, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('.letter').keypress(function ()
    {
        $(this).next().focus();
    });
});
```

Check this [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fEEa7/). It need some validation too, but I guess main idea is clear.

Answer (score 2):

[lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/) ([wiki](https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js/wiki)) is a JavaScript library that provides functionality very similar to what you are looking for.

On the other hand, if you are looking to implement your own solution, this is how I would do it:

1) Grab the paragraph you want to "boxify"

2) For each letter of the target paragraph, create a new input element with a unique ID and a property marking the letter it replaces. Style it with css until satisfied.

3) Attach event listeners (keyup / keypress) to every input created this way (distinguished by class name).

4) Upon validation, progress to the next input field with the same class name (via tab index ordering or manually by shifting focus to the next input field).

Answer (score 0):

You can use maxlength attributes of input tag

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="1">
```

And change css to adjust width of input.