# Limit the number of characters in a separate input field for each character

Tags: html, css

I have an input field and would want to give it a look and feel of a character-by-character box field (image below).

[image]

My HTML and CSS are written below. They work fine except the max length I want the user to enter is 6. When the user enters the 6th character, the boxes move out of place, even though the 7th character is NOT added to the field. **How can I avoid this?**

**First 5 characters added:**

[image]

**6th character added, the alignment is out:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" maxlength="6" id="text"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
#text{
    background-image:
    url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4oAWWCcNNz4/Tjr3nKNyVUI/AAAAAAAAPLU/Pouua-pNsEY/s1600/sq.gif");    
    width: 114px;
    height: 18px;
    background-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 12px;
}
```

Comment: I did not notice anything wrong with it, could you elaborate: https://jsfiddle.net/v92b5L8c/

Comment: It because of the spacing. When you enter the last letter, the field still needs to adding the spacing after it to prepare for the next letter...even though there wont be. `letter-spacing` is applied after every typed letter

Comment: @lucas: I have updated the question

Comment: @m_callens: I need spacing for the first 6 characters for sure. What do you suggest to avoid spacing any further than 6 characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using some JS you can blur the input.

Obs.: I did some adjusts in css..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#text").on('keypress', function(e){
   if($(this).val().length > 4) {
     var value = $(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
      $(this).val(value);
     $(this).blur();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#text{
    background-image:
    url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4oAWWCcNNz4/Tjr3nKNyVUI/AAAAAAAAPLU/Pouua-pNsEY/s1600/sq.gif");    
    width: 114px;
    height: 18px;
    background-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 6.5px;
    letter-spacing: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxlength="6" id="text"/>
```

Comment: There is a slight issue with this: enter 1-6 in the boxes, remove the number 3 only and then enter 8 at the same position of the cursor. Apparently the new entry is at the end of the box now.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to add another, wrapping element around the input then you can apply the background to that instead:

```css
#wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4oAWWCcNNz4/Tjr3nKNyVUI/AAAAAAAAPLU/Pouua-pNsEY/s1600/sq.gif");    
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  background-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 7px;
}
#text {
  background: none;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 3px 0 0;
  border: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="text" maxlength="6" id="text"/>
</div>
```

The input element will then spill out of the container slightly, which is something to be aware of if there is other content flowing around it.

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript. When the last number is entered the cursor will be set to the first position thus the display will be correct.

```
<script>
function gotoStart(waarde) {
    if (waarde.length == 6) {
        $("#text").get(0).setSelectionRange(0, 0);
        //set the focus to the next field\button to make the shifting of the cursor even less apparent if you want
        $("#text1").focus();
    }
}
</script>

<input type="text" maxlength="6" id="text" onkeyup="gotoStart(this.value)" />
```

Answer (score -4):

Looks like your letter spacing is too much.

Lower it by a pixel

```
letter-spacing: 11px;
```

Comment: While this does stop the overflow issue, it causes the letter to be out of sync with the boxes