# HTML & CSS Split input form - char by char

Tags: html, css, input, split

I try to split input field to make something like this:

[image]

But I'm stuck and I didn't found anything that help me. I find something similar but isn't what I want:

```css
input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  width: 400px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, dimgrey 0, dimgrey 1ch, transparent 0, transparent 1.5ch) 0 100%/52% 2px no-repeat;
  color: dimgrey;
  font-family: monospace;
  letter-spacing: .5ch;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="20" />
```

The only requirement is to use only HTML and CSS.
I would appreciate very much if someone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38747017/1675954

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it to look closer with these changes to `background`, `letter-spacing`, and `padding-left`:

```css
input[type="text"] {
  border: solid 1px dimgrey;
  width: 400px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #ffffff 0px, #ffffff 19px, #000000 20px);
  color: dimgrey;
  font-family: monospace;
  letter-spacing: 1.75ch;
  padding-left: 0.8ch;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="20" />
```