# Split text input to few cells using CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to split input to few cells. I want to draw few blocks and in each user press, one of the blocks will fill. Something like this:

[image]

What is the right way to do it?

This is the code of the form:

```
  <div class="wrap-log-in-form" *ngIf="step == 'pass'">      

  <input type="text" class="spliting-input"  maxlength="6">

  <div class="buttens-log-in"> 
      <input type="button" value="אמת">
      <input type="button" value="קבל הודעה בטלפון">      
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your complete code. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML & CSS Split input form - char by char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201626/html-css-split-input-form-char-by-char)

Comment: it's not quite the same. i do not think that you can do with this solution, what appears in the picture. he just draw lines inside the input, not cut it.

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui Please see my edit

Comment: Use a hidden input field to actually get the input, and show the input characters on your visible inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS background image on the `input` and try to use `letter-spacing` to get the text to fall in the correct areas, BUT this is really hard and not a great solution.

The issue is each device and browser displays characters slightly differently so the spacing is always off just a bit. This is pretty hacky but works if you only have access to the CSS.

**A better solution**

Use Javascript to parse the input and split each character into its own element with unique placement and background styling.